# Is S#arp applicable in classic ASP.NET or even WinForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, s#arp-architecture

I know S#arp architecture is built for ASP.NET MVC. But I'm wondering if it can be used in classic ASP.NET (WebForms) or even desktop applications like WinForms or WPF.

Thnkas a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iain,
    You most definitely could use S#arp Architecture in an application other than ASP.NET MVC. I use it to power several console applications and we have a few windows services running it as well.

You would want to look at the S#arp Architecture Contrib project to use it in a non MVC or Web Form app. To use it in web forms, you would use spin it up as you would a MVC application, but using it in your web forms would be slightly different. In this case, look for an MVVM or MVP solution and replace as you need.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from your question, you should have a look at the [MVP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx). You can create your own Models and Views by yourself with asp.net forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about WebForms or WPF but if you want to use it for WinForms, check this out:

[wiki.sharparchitecture.net/ContribNonWebHowTo.ashx](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/ContribNonWebHowTo.ashx)

I have found it to be very workable.